# How to get kubernetes host IP from inside of a pod?

Tags: kubernetes

Let's say we have a frontend and a backend pods running in a kubernetes cluster.

Both pods have corresponding services exposing them on the host (type: `NodePort`). In the end, the frontend uses `<Host IP>:<Port 1>`, and the backend runs on `<Host IP>:<Port 2>`.

How to find out the host IP so that it could be used in the frontend pod (to be defined as a value of a variable)? Tried with setting `localhost`, but it didn't work, so probably the exact IP has to be defined.

Comment: why do you want to use the ip and not access the backend via its service name?

Comment: At the moment, the frontend app limitations stop me from doing it this way. It will change in the near future, but at the prototyping stage I have to use the exact IP.

Comment: not having to know the ip is the whole point of using the name, since the pods could be on different nodes and then they can be evicted and spun up on another node too; the ip can change, the name shouldn't. If the sole purpose of this is POC, lookup and hardcode the ip, it sounds terrible, but so as trying to find how to dynamically find and use other pods/nodes ips :)

Comment: The problem is, when I set it up as an environment variable: `- name: REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL \ value: "plg-backend"`, the IP doesn't get resolved, all calls from frontend are addressed to `plg-backend:30122`.

Answer (score 7):

Use the [downward API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/downward-api-volume-expose-pod-information/):

```
spec:
  image: ...
  env:
   - name: REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL
     valueFrom:
       fieldRef:
         fieldPath: status.hostIP
```

Comment: I got this: `error validating data: ValidationError(Pod.spec.containers[0].env[2].valueFrom.fieldRef): invalid type for io.k8s.api.core.v1.ObjectFieldSelector: got "string", expected "map"`.

Comment: Sorry, missed a step. see edit.

Comment: OK, now the pod starts up and works. However, the `hostIP` is the internal IP of a node. Is it any way to get the externally exposed IP?

Comment: As far as Kubernetes is concerned, there is no such thing as an "externally exposed IP".

Answer (score 0):

Update "deployment.yaml" like below
[image]